# Are Mahtan, Nerdanel, Maedhros, Amrod and Amras the only red-headed Elves?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Are the they the only Elves or at least Noldor that bear red hair?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the Noldor, Vanyar, and other tribes that had a major role in the Silmarillion, there were an uncounted number of Elves living in Arda who we never learn anything about. Some of them might have had red hair.

http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Avari

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Tolkien ever stated that Nerdanel had red hair but rather it was assumed she did. But I believe you are right in that their family (and members of their kin) possessed red hair. There's probably a letter or script from Tolkien mentioning this but from the [Lord of the Rings wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Nerdanel) atleast:

> ...**they are the only attested examples of elves with red hair**. Nerdanel's father Mahtan and three of her sons (Maedhros, Amrod, and Amras) are described by Tolkien as having red hair (actually a reddish brown) and this is described as a trait "of Nerdanel's kin". **Nerdanel's own hair color is never specifically stated**, although it is said that she possessed a ruddy complexion and so it is assumed that Tolkien did indeed intend Nerdanel to have red hair.